# Using partial match with filter and VSTACK

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-filter

With help from some of this site's suggestions, I've got the following formula to pull from several worksheets:

```
=FILTER(VSTACK(FRR:SOD!G3:M200),
  (VSTACK(FRR:SOD!K3:K200)<>"")*
  (VSTACK(FRR:SOD!K3:K200)="ABC XXXX"))
```

Is there a way to filter for a partial match within "ABC XXXX"?  Think of ABC as a location, and XXXX as a job/position at that location. I would like to be able to pull everyone assigned to ABC to a new worksheet then filter by job/position. Is that possible?

Comment: There is no sample data posted, hence only by assuming, one could try the following: `=LET(α, VSTACK(FRR:SOD!G3:M200), δ, INDEX(α,,5), FILTER(α, (δ<>"")*(1-ISNA(XMATCH("ABC *",δ,2))),"Not Found"))` or instead of using `1-ISNA(` you can use `ISNUMBER()` --> `=LET(α, VSTACK(FRR:SOD!G3:M200), δ, INDEX(α,,5), FILTER(α, (δ<>"")*(ISNUMBER(XMATCH("ABC *",δ,2))),"Not Found"))`

Comment: I suggest you edit your ask as I equate pull and filter to mean the same thing, so don't understand what the purpose of stating it as two separate parameters. Otherwise I would probably just use somthing like `LEFT(VSTACK(...),3)="ABC"`

Comment: I think this is what you were suggesting, found in a different forum:  =FILTER(VSTACK(FRR:SOD!G3:M200),LEFT(VSTACK(FRR:SOD!K3:K200),3)="ABC").  I couldn't understand your idea since you abbreviated it (I'm still getting proficient with the Excel lingo).  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Will your location always be 3characters in length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate everyone's input, although some of it is a bit complex as I'm still learning bit by bit.  This formula from another forum worked exactly as I needed, and was easy for me to make sense of:

=FILTER(VSTACK(FRR:SOD!G3:M200),LEFT(VSTACK(FRR:SOD!K3:K200),3)="ABC")

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
=LET(
     α, VSTACK(FRR:SOD!G3:M200), 
     δ, INDEX(α,,5), 
     FILTER(α, (δ<>"")*(1-ISNA(XMATCH("ABC *",δ,2))),"Not Found"))
```

---

- Using `LET()` function helps to define variables and makes easier to read without repeating same formulas.
- `α` variable is defined as using `VSTACK()` which appends multiple sheets data into one consisting of range `G3:M200` from sheets `FRR` and `SOD`
- `δ` variable is defined as using `INDEX()` function to extract the `5th` from the array returned in `α`
- Using `XMATCH()` with a wildcard operator **`Asterix`**<sup>*</sup> which means `Zero` and any number of characters. In this use case it is used location `ABC *` and checks for any location starting with `ABC` and ending with any assigned `job/position` at the same location from the array `δ`.
- If there is a match found then we can use either `ISNUMBER()` to return `TRUE` or `1-ISNA()` also can be used which does the same, i.e. first `ISNA()` returns `TRUE` where it `#N/A` error next subtracted from resulting in `TRUE` which is same as doing with `ISNUMBER()`
- Lastly, wrapping within `FILTER()` function to extract where there are `TRUE`.

---

**Notes:**

• Excel has **3 wildcards** one can use in your formulas:

1. **Asterisk** (`*`) --> Zero or more characters.
2. **Question mark** (`?`) --> any one character.
3. **Tilde** (`~`) --> escape for literal characters (`~*`), a literal question mark (`~?`), or a literal tilde (`~~`).

---

Answer (score 0):

*There should be many combinations in case of Partial Match,,,, below is one I would like to share with you.*

```
=FILTER(VSTACK(FRR:SOD!G3:M200),
  (VSTACK(FRR:SOD!K3:K200<>"")*
  ((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("NEW*", VSTACK(FRR:SOD!K3:K200)))) +
  (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*MANAGER", VSTACK(FRR:SOD!K3:K200)))) > 0))
```

- Now let me explain about  ((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("NEW*"
- Here in NEW* ,, * is Wild Card character assumes more the One
  Characters.
- It may assume Locations like NEW Delhi, NEW York, NEW Jersey and
  others.
- Another is  (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*MANAGER" , where *MANAGER may assume
  EDP MANAGER, SALES MANAGER and others.

**N.B.**

- You may use another Wild Card Character  **?** as is needed.
- Additionally [Check this
  link](https://excelmee.com/excel-formulas/lookup/wildcards-in-filter-function-in-excel/)
  .